# criar numero aleatório em python começando pelo ano

Tags: python-3.x

olá estou tentando criar uma variável para me retornar um numero de protocolo pegando o ano atual depois 4 casas a frente começando do menor para o maior, exemplo.   20180001, 20180002 etc.

para pegar somente o ano usei

```
def numero_solicitacao():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now.year
```

a duvida é como juntar a variável com o valor do ano mais as casas crescentes na frente?

Comment: Olá Gustavo, quer retornar uma variável do tipo `2018+ (4 dígitos aleatórios)`?

Comment: isso amigo porem não somando os valores  já tentei criar a variável pegando o ano e outra o numero randômico porém ou retornou ou a soma dos dois ou uma tupla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema de "concatenar" os números basta usar matemática, se você está usando o ano com 4 dígitos como base, basta você multiplicar o ano por 10.000, ou seja, você vai adicionar 4 zeros a direita do ano. Depois disso basta somar ao próximo número.

```
2018 * 10000 + 1 # 20180001
2018 * 10000 + 2 # 20180002
2018 * 10000 + 3 # 20180003
# ...
```

Exemplo de um generator que faz o que você precisa:

```
def numero_solicitacao(ano = None, numero_inicial = 1):
    ano_atual = ano or date.today().year
    numero = numero_inicial

    while numero <= 9999:
        yield ano_atual * 10000 + numero
        numero += 1

gen_numero = numero_solicitacao()
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20180001
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20180002
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20180003

gen_numero = numero_solicitacao(2011, 500)
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20110500
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20110501
print(next(gen_numero))  # 20110502
```

Note que eu defini os parâmetros  `ano` e `numero_inicial` para que você possa iniciar no número que for necessário, dessa maneira você pode pegar o último registro que você tem no banco de dados e usar o generator para ele seguir daquele número em diante.

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/ProfitableWittyTheories) com o código funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

baseado na sua resposta Fernando sobrescrevi o método save do model para pegar o  ANO mais duas casa 00 mais o ID

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super (Solicitacao, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    ano_corrente = datetime.datetime.now()
    if not self.numero_descricao:
        self.numero_descricao = f"{ano_corrente.year}00{self.id}"
        self.save
```

deu certo muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos!!!